# $A\in M_n(F)$ is called cyclic, I have to show , the representation of A has the following form

Tags: linear-algebra

$F$ ia a field. a matrix
$A\in M_n(F)$ is called cyclic if there is a vector $v\in M_{1\times n}(F)$ such that $\{v, vA, . . . , vA^{n-1}\}$ is
a basis for $M_{1\times n}(F)$ as a left vector space over $F$. I have to show , the representation of A in the
above basis has the following form
 ‎$\begin{pmatrix}‎
‎0 & 1 & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\ 0 & 0 &1 & \ldots & 0 \\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots \\ 0 & 0 \ldots & \ldots & 0 & 1 \\ a_{1} & a_{2} & \ldots & a_{n-1} & a_{n} ‎
‎\end{pmatrix}$‎, for som $a_1‎ , ‎a_2 ,‎ ‎\ldots‎ , ‎a_n \in F$‎.
‎

Answer (score 0):

Hint: There exists $a_1,...,a_n\in F$ such that $$vA^n=a_1v+a_2vA+...+a_nvA^{n-1}$$ and for every $i<n-1$, $(vA^i)A=vA^{i+1}$.

Comment: Hi, Thanke you Nitrogen. Can I ask you explain more, please. By you're answer the representation of A is $\begin{pmatrix}‎
 ‎0 & 0 &\ldots & 0 &‎ -‎a_1\\‎
‎1 &0 & \ldots & 0 &‎ -a_2\\‎
‎0 & 1 & \ldots & 0 &‎ -‎a_3\\‎
‎\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots\\‎
‎0 & 0 & \ldots & 1 &‎ -‎a_{n}‎
‎\end{pmatrix}.$ not above?

Comment: Yes exactly, but now you have to be careful because you wrote you question with multiplication on the right by $A$, so you should take the transpose of this matrix, and the result will be in the desired form.

Comment: Ok, multiplication on the right by $A$ But Why we take the transpose of this matrix?Cen you tell me please.

Comment: Because $(vA)^t=A^tv^t$.

Comment: yes. Thanke you Nitrogen, thanke you very much.